# Mule File Inbound to HTTP Outbound

Tags: mule

I have a case where I need to poll a directory on my file system. Each file that is added to that directory needs to be posted to an HTTP endpoint.

The HTTP endpoint is available on "/rest/latest/file". Using postman, I've verified that the REST call works with the following settings:

- POST
- basic auth
- form-data:
- - key = file
- - value = Selected a file from my file system (using a dialog)

My mule flow currently looks like this:

```
<file:connector name="File" autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" moveToPattern="#[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename']].backup" moveToDirectory="src/main/resources/output" doc:name="File"/>
<flow name="importdataqualityresultsFlow1" doc:name="importdataqualityresultsFlow1">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="src/main/resources/input" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    <set-payload value="#[['file' :#[message.inboundAttachments['text.txt']]]]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="80" path="rest/latest/file" method="POST" user="Admin" password="admin" contentType="application/form-data" doc:name="HTTP"/>
</flow>
```

I can tell in my application logs that the user logs in using basic auth, after which I get a stack trace.

Any help / pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a map payload with the form fields:

```
<flow name="importdataqualityresultsFlow1">
  <file:inbound-endpoint path="src/main/resources/input" />
  <object-to-string-transformer />
  <set-payload value="#[['file': message.payload]]" />
  <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="80" path="rest/latest/file" method="POST" user="Admin" password="admin" contentType="application/form-data" />
</flow>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately no luck. I changed line 4 to <set-payload value="#[['file': message.payload]]" doc:name="Set Payload"/> as there is only one key value pair requested in the call.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. What exception do you get? Pastebin and link it here.

Comment: Mmmh not very useful: we don't see why the server 500s for the request it gets. Can you make it be more accurate in what it logs? Also, try putting an HTTP proxy between Mule and the server to see exactly what Mule POSTs.

Comment: will do, any recommendations for the HTTP proxy?

Comment: if you're an Eclipse user, this is a simple option: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Frwtcpvw.html